# DNS can't be reached updating name server in Route 53

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

After upgrading my instance type in EC2, I have (stupidly) deleted and recreated a new hosted zone for my domain, and put the new instance public IP.

I have followed the following steps:

1. created new hosted zones
2. put ttl value to 60 sec in the name server administration (on the left panel)
3. copied the server names list found in the hosted zones NS panel to the server names list in the "Registered domains" page and updated
4. received a "succeed" message in my mail box

[image]

[image]

Accessing directly with the public IP address work fine however I still can't access my domain name.

And get the error: This site can’t be reached - server DNS address could not be found.

Did I miss a step ? How long should I wait? Could the problem be something else ?

Comment: You seem to be confused about whether this is a DNS or web server issue. You need to sort this difference out first. Starting with DNS. Try to query your domain's name servers directly with `nslookup`, `host`, or `dig`, etc... and see if you get the response your looking for. If you do, it may just be a matter of waiting. You need to determine if this is a domain name problem before you bother with your web server. That's totally separate.

Comment: Your nginx config is completely irrelevant to a DNS question. And if you don't show your actual domain name and the configuration of your zone file, nobody will be able to help you. Also, "can't access" is not very helpful - the actual error message might give a clue as to *why* it doesn't work.

Comment: If you properly corrected your mistake, it's probably just a matter of propagation delay.  The only way to clarify that is to poll (dig/nslookup) different name servers to see what information they got.  Without your domain name, it's a waste of time.

Comment: Question edited (deleted the irrelevant part about nginx)

Comment: When I nslookup on one of my name servers, I get some result. But I can hardly said if it is correct or not. 

For example : 
nslookup ns-612.awsdns-12.net

Give me : 

Server: 192.168.3.1
Address: 192.168.3.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: ns-612.awsdns-12.net
Address: 205.251.194.100

None of those IP addresses are known to me. Is this a correct response ?

Comment: @RaphaelTokyo Do it like this: `nslookup <your fqdn> <nameserver address>` e.g. `nslookup google.ca 8.8.8.8` gives me `216.58.192.163`

Comment: Added screenshot of the Route 53 panels with all info included.

Comment: Just tried : 

nslookup raphaelleray.com ns-612.awsdns-12.net
Server:  ns-612.awsdns-12.net
Address: 205.251.194.100#53

Name: raphaelleray.com
Address: 54.199.144.199

Sound like a good result... but the site is still "not found"...

Comment: Actual error message is : This site can’t be reached

raphaelleray.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

Comment: @RaphaelTokyo Like I said as well as Jenny D, you may need to wait for DNS propagation. Try to query other DNS servers. Your regular DNS server probably just has the old zone cached. What do you get when you do `ping raphaelleray.com` ? Because I get `54.199.144.199`. That correct right? If you ping and it doesn't work, then it's your DNS or ISPs DNS... just wait. If you ping and it's `54.199.144.199`, then start looking at web server problems.

Comment: @RaphaelTokyo FYI, your nginx is responding on `54.199.144.199`, just checked.

Comment: I got : ping: cannot resolve raphaelleray.com: Unknown host :-(
I must wait I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

`raphaelleray.com` works fine (https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/raphaelleray.com), but you're lacking an `A` record for `www.raphaelleray.com`.

If the non-www doesn't work, you're encountering DNS caching.

Comment: I flush my cache on my computer, so it might be a problem from ISPs DNS caching.